# include all where cases to make one sql query

Tags: php, sql

Here is the code

```
if ($st) active_code = '1';

if (!$st) active_code > '0';


SELECT username FROM users WHERE active_code = '1'

SELECT username FROM users WHERE active_code > '0'
```

Is there is a way to make then one sql query ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write it in one line? You can't have it in one SQL query because you are checking for two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cond = $st ? "= '1'":" > '0'";
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE active_code $cond";
```

Comment: This may work, but it's not good practice to minimize code like that; at a first glance it should be more or less obvious what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

Just define a variable that will hold the condition:

```
if ($st) {
    $condition = "active_code = '1'";
} else {
    $condition = "active_code > '0'";
}

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE $cond";
```

Comment: `$condition=($st) ? "active_code = '1'" : "active_code > '0'";`
and `$sql = "... $condition";`

Comment: @Amir whatever floats your boat :) shorter isn't always better.

Comment: @Jack put `$condition` instead of `$cond` in your `query`